# How to draw a rect within another one

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rect

I got a code that based on user's input, draws a rectangle. I need to create another rect within the first one as shown in the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPj8P.jpg

I got the following code until now. 
https://codepen.io/newtz/pen/MWWKRYG

```
    function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeRect(zoomedX(50), zoomedY(50), zoomed(width), zoomed(height));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you draw a rectangle, you can draw a smaller one inside.
For example, if the width and height equal 100, then you will call:

```
context.strokeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Then you can draw the smaller rectangle using the previous values:

```
context.strokeRect(0 + 10, 0 + 10, 100 - 20, 100 - 20);
```

To allow this, you have to give parameters to your `draw()` function, so can can make the position and size of the new rectangles vary:

```
draw()  =>  draw(x, y, width, height)
```

In your code, declare two variables `x` and `y` and assign default values (50 in your code).

Then your `draw()` function:

```
function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeRect(zoomedX(50), zoomedY(50), zoomed(width), zoomed(height));

}
```

Change like this:

```
function draw(x, y, width, height) {      
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeRect(zoomedX(x), zoomedY(y), zoomed(width), zoomed(height));
}
```

Now it has parameters. We also need to remove the clearing instruction: this function is designed to draw, only this. Moreover, if you don't remove the clearing line, each drawing will remove previously drawn rectangles.

Finally, call the `draw(...)` functions in your callbacks:

```
$width.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    width = this.value;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    draw(x, y, width, height);
    draw(x + 5, y + 5, width - 10, height - 10);
    draw(x + 10, y + 10, width - 20, height - 20);
}, false);
```

Same for the `height`. So each time you update the `width` or the `height` value, it will draw 3 nested rectangles.

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/jzeygapL/4/

For the test, I created a `drawMultiple(x, y, width, height)` function which draws three rectangles:

```
function drawMultiple(x, y, width, height) {
    draw(x, y, width, height);
    draw(x + 5, y + 5, width - 10, height - 10);
    draw(x + 10, y + 10, width - 20, height - 20);
}
```